# execute procedure for a sequence of elements (execute theProc (select id from table))

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to execute the procedure `deleteQuestion` for each element that was returned by this select query:

```
select id from questions where Stuff = @Stuff

execute deleteQuestion id
```

something like:
 `execute deleteQuestion each(select id fom questions where Stuff = @Stuff)`

anybody knows how ?

Comment: What parameters does the `deleteQuestions` SP take?  Must you use the `deleteQuestions` SP are you free to consider alternative approaches?

Comment: @Daniel Renshaw the deleteQuestion SP takes id as a parameter

Comment: A cursor can be used as @klausbyskov suggests but this is slow and cumbersome.  If you can avoid using the SP, set-based statements would be far more efficient and in the SQL spirit.

Comment: @Daniel Renshaw the deleteQuestion SP is deleting an entire subtree starting from the lowest child so I don't know if I could do it in another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this:

```
declare @sqlstr nvarchar(max)

set @sqlstr = ''

select  @sqlstr = @sqlstr + ' exec deleteQuestion ' + cast(q.id as nvarchar(max))
from Questions q where stuff = @stuff

exec (@sqlstr)
```

I've been told that this approach is much faster than a cursor

Answer (score 5):

Use a [cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx):

```
DECLARE @Id INT
DECLARE your_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT id from questions where Stuff = @Stuff 

OPEN your_cursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM your_cursor 
INTO @Id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    execute deleteQuestion @Id

    FETCH NEXT FROM your_cursor 
        INTO @Id

END 
CLOSE your_cursor
DEALLOCATE your_cursor
```